# How to filter masterdata using more than 6 criterias

Tags: movilizer

Assuming I have a masterdata pool containing customer data. I want to filter masterdata entities using queryMasterdata. 
A masterdata entity - by definition - has 6 filter attributes, 3 string based and 3 numeric, which can be used for filtering with good performance because the values are indexed.

What if I want to filter for customers in that pool using more than 6 criterias of type string?

For instance:

- First Name
- Last Name
- City
- Country
- State
- Street
- Occupation

I am aware that some of the criterias should rather be predefined values in a productive scenario for usability reasons. But let's assume all 7 filter criterias are treated as strings. How to model / structure the masterdata to make sure that all criterias are operating on indexed values of masterdata, when there are only 3 string filters available in one masterdata entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use more than 3 string filters, you may split your masterdata into several pools. You can create separate pools for the person details and the location details or group them according to your preference. Then, you may link the data between the pools by making use of the numeric filters as foreign keys.

Kind Regards,
Ana